# If $V$ is a finite dimensional with two norms then $\Vert v\Vert_1 \leq c\Vert v\Vert_2 $

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_1$ and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_2$ are inner products on $V$ with corresponding norms $\Vert \cdot\Vert_1$ and $\Vert \cdot\Vert_2$. Prove that there exists a positive number $c$ such that

$$\Vert v\Vert_1 \leq c\Vert v\Vert_2 $$

for every $v\in V$.

Please help me with this question?

**Edit (to be reopen).** Of course, this result is a particular case of the proved result in the [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754159/equivalence-of-norms-proof). But it is not a duplicate because here we want to use the fact that the norms are induced by inner products. So, is there a different proof for this specific case (where the norms has a specific form)?

Comment: @Pedro: why would one want to use that fact? It does not seem the argument becomes any simpler, rather the opposite. (That the original is phrased as it is phrased could just as well be due to no abstract notion of norm being introduced.)

Comment: @quid I thought there is a simpler proof (and you can be right in your parenthesis).

Comment: @Pedro: thanks for the reply. Thinking about it, there may be a slightly  simpler proof in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $V$ with respect to $\langle\, , \, \rangle_1$. One approach is to note that for $x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)\in \Bbb C^n$ and $y = (y_1,\dots,y_n)\in \Bbb C^n$, we have
$$
\left\langle \sum_{i=1}^n x_i v_i, \sum_{j=1}^n y_jv_j \right\rangle_2 = y^*Ax
$$
where $A$ is the matrix whose entries are $a_{ij} = \langle v_i,v_j \rangle$.

From there, it suffices to note (or show) that the function
$$
f(x) = \frac{\|x\|_2}{\|x\|_1} = \frac{x^*Ax}{x^*x}
$$
attains a maximum.  In order to do so, it helps to consider the restriction of $f$ to the set $\{x:\|x\|_1 = 1\}$.

Comment: How do you show that the function attains a maximum? (Of course it is easy by continuity and compactness but I wonder if you really want to use this.)

Comment: I did really want to use continuity and compactness

Comment: This answer pretty much boils down to the fact that finite dimensional normed spaces are locally compact. I suspect that the OP wants an answer that relies more on the fact that the space in question is a Hilbert space (not that I can think of one, actually).

Answer (score 6):

Let $(e_1, \dots, e_n)$ be an orthonormal basis with respect to the second scalar product.

Then, for $v = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i$ one has  $\|v \|_2 = \sqrt{\langle v,v \rangle_2} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|^2} \ge \max_{i=1, \dots, n} |a_i| $.

Now note $\| v\|_1 \le \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i| \| e_i \|_1  \le m \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i| \le mn \max_{i=1, \dots, n} |a_i| \le mn  \|v\|_2$ where $m = \max_{i=1, \dots, n} \|e_i\|_1$.

Comment: Thanks. Great answer!

Comment: Can you clarify why $|v|_1 \le \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i||e|_1$?

Comment: @user13 we have by assumption $v = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i$; and $\|v\|_1 =  \|\sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i\|$.  Then  by the triangle inequality $ \|\sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i\| \le \sum_{i=1}^n \|a_i e_i \|_1$ then use $\|a_i e_i \|_1 = |a_i| \|e_i\|$

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume we're working with a real vector space (proof is similar for a complex vector space). The statement is equivalent to $\langle v,v\rangle_1 \leq c \langle v,v\rangle_2$.

Every inner product $\langle v,w\rangle_A$ can be written as $v^T A w$ where $A$ is positive definite. Let $A$ be the matrix for inner product 1, and $B$ be the matrix for inner product 2.

Let the smallest eigenvalue of $B$ be $b$ and the largest eigenvalue of $A$ be $a$. Let $c = \frac{a}{b}>0$. Then,
$$\frac{v^T A v}{v^T v} \leq a,\qquad \frac{v^T B v}{v^T v} \geq b.$$ This follows from the [Rayleigh quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient).

So, $$c \frac{v^T B v}{v^T v} \geq c b = a \geq \frac{v^T A v}{v^T v}. $$

Now, multiply both sides by $v^T v$, write $v^T A v = \langle v,v\rangle_1$ and $v^T B v = \langle v,v\rangle_2$ in the expression above, take square roots of both sides and you get your desired statement.