# Prove that there exists a positive number $c$ such that $|v|_1 \le c*|v|_2$ for every $v \in V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $<.;.>_1, <.;.>_2$ are inner products on $V$ with corresponding norms $|.|_1$ and $|.|_2$. Prove that there exists a positive number $c$ such that
>   $$|v|_1 \le c*|v|_2$$ for every $v \in V$.

Suppose there exists some $v \not=0 \in V$ such that $|v|_1 > c|v|_2$ for every $c > 0$. However, since this should hold for every positive $c$ then it should hold in particular for $c = |v|_1/|v|_2$. Thus, $|v|_1 > \frac{|v|_1}{|v|_2}|v|_2 = |v|_1$ we get a contradiction.

Is this kind of logic plausible in this case? Note: I saw an answer ([If $V$ is a finite dimensional with two norms then $\Vert v\Vert_1 \leq c\Vert v\Vert_2 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583182/if-v-is-a-finite-dimensional-with-two-norms-then-vert-v-vert-1-leq-c-vert-v)) to this question. However, I am trying to avoid using matrices at this point since the book (Linear Algebra Done Right - Axler) is doing so too (at least, I think so). Also, I would like to check if this kind of logic is appropriate.

Comment: You are assuming by contradiction something that is always false: for any $v \neq 0$, you can always find a $c$ such that $|v|_1 \leq c |v|_2$: as you noticed yourself, you can choose $c = |v|_2 / |v|_1$. The negation of the statement for which you can reason by contradiction is: for all $c$ there exists some $v_c \neq 0$ such that $|v_c|_1 > c |v_c|_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that doesn't use matrices or anything about compactness.

Suppose that $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is an orthonormal basis relative to $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle_2$. Now, consider an arbitrary $v = a_1 v_1 + \cdots + a_n v_n$.  We note that $|v|_2 = |a_1|^2 + \cdots + |a_n|^2$.  $|\cdot|_1$ is a norm, which means that it satisfies the triangle inequality, so that
$$
\begin{align}
|v|_1 &= \left|\sum_{j=1}^n a_jv_j\right|_2 \leq \sum_{j=1}^n |a_j v_j|_1 \leq
\sum_{j=1}^n |a_j| |v_j|_1 
\\ & \leq 
\sum_{j=1}^n |a_j| \max_{j=1,\dots,n}|v_j|_1 =  
\max_{j=1,\dots,n}|v_j|_1 \cdot \sum_{j=1}^n |a_j|
\end{align}
$$
Now, we note that for any non-negative $x_1,\dots,x_n$, we have 
$$
\frac{x_1 + \cdots + x_n}{n} \leq \sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2} \implies
x_1 + \cdots + x_n \leq n \cdot \sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}.
$$
Let $M = \max_{j=1,\dots,n}|v_j|_1$. Combining the two inequalities above gives us
$$
|v|_1 \leq M(|a_1| + \cdots + |a_n|) \leq M \cdot n \cdot \sqrt{|a_1|^2 + \cdots + |a_n|^2} = M \cdot n \cdot |v|_2.
$$
Thus, we have our desired result with $c = M\cdot n$.

Answer (score 1):

It is a standard theorem of linear algebra that $|v|_1$ and $|v|_2$ can be *simultaneously diagonalized*. This means that we can adopt in $V$ a coordinate system $(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ such that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_2$ is the standard euclidean scalar product, and that the matrix of $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_1$ is diagonal. In terms of this coordinate system there are numbers
$$0<\lambda_1\leq\ldots\leq\lambda_n$$
such that
$$|v|_1=\sqrt{\lambda_1 v_1^2+\ldots+\lambda_n v_n^2}\ \leq\ \sqrt{\lambda_n}\> |v|_2\ .$$