# on a characterization of convergent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ a matrix. It's known that the following statements are equivalent:

1) $A$ is convergent, namely $\lim_{k\to\infty}(A^k)_{ij}=0$

2) $\lim_{k\to\infty}||A^k||=0$ for every natural norm

How can I prove it? In particular I am interested in "2) implies 1)" since my idea about the other implication is that you can get the thesis simply by continuity of the matrix norms.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All norms on $\mathbb R^{n\times n}\equiv \mathbb R^{n^2}$ are equivalent. In particular, there exists $C>1$ such that
$$
C^{-1}\|B\|\le\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nB_{ij}^2\right)^{1/2}\le C\|B\|
$$
for **any** matrix $B\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$. Now replace $B$ by $A^k$ and let $k\to\infty$.

Comment: Two questions: 1) in the middle you wrote the norm 2 of $B$ ($||B||_2$) right?   2) why there exists that $C$? I know that if two norms are equivalent then we have $m||B||'\le ||B||\le M||B||'$ for certains $m,M$. So, is it essential that $C>1$?. Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes and it is not essential that $C>1$ (if you have any $C>0$ you can always consider a bigger $C$; actually notice that necessarily $C\ge1$). As for all norms being equivalent have a look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754159/equivalence-of-norms-proof

Comment: Last thing: do you agree that 1 implies 2 is due by continuity of the norm? thank you again

Comment: I do. On the other hand, how do you prove continuity? Essentially you should prove the first inequality in my answer. So, the two arguments can be considered "equivalent".

Comment: I can't see the "equivalence". For me proving the continuity in a point, say the matrix $A$, means that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a matrix $\delta$ such that $abs(||A+\delta||-||A||)<\epsilon$. Is it incorrect?

Comment: I see. But it shouldn't be like that. The function should be $f(A)=\|A\|$ but before saying what continuity is you need to say how do you measure the distance on the domain. Otherwise, what would be the meaning of "$|f(A)-f(B)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $|A-B|<\delta$"? What would be $|A-B|$ here? What I am saying is that you can take it to be the $2$-norm. On the other hand, you cannot take the norm $\|\cdot\|$ since it would read $|\|A\|-\|B\||<\varepsilon$ whenever $\|A-B\|<\delta$, and in the last one cannot use your 1) since that hypothesis doesn't come in terms of $\|A-B\|$.

Comment: Ok now I think the point is: it's always true that the function $f(A)=||A||$ is continuous whenever we take a matrix norm $||.||$ to measure the distance on the domain, but in the case of my problem I have to take the norm 2 on the domain in order to use the hypothesis and to get statement 2). Is this ok now?

Comment: Well, yes for "whenever we take a matrix norm" but not "I have to take the norm 2 on the domain". You would get the same with say the $1$-norm. Really you only have to use one norm that lets you use hypothesis 1) (for example the $2$-norm, or the $1$-norm, etc).